# Virtual Assistants knowledge

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am studying about artificial intelligence
How did the virtual assistants analyze questions?
Example: when I said "Way from New York City to Washington DC" , va opened google map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I would develop that stuff myself I'd probably would use pattern like
If ({a} {linker} {b}) where a and b are in list of cities on map or something related to that and linker is word like "from" or "to" i would run google maps with, also if any of remaining words would signal that it is map related stuff, like "location", "map", "route" and so on...

Just a guess but I think this should work like that

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any idea that which programming language will you prefer to develop this project but I highly recommend Python. It is object-oriented, high level and extensive support libraries. Moreover, I don't know what is your targeted OS for this project, you unfortunately have not specified it and maybe you will choose Android OS(for mobile application you may use [Python](http://www.qpython.com/)) so Python may not be a good option for you. But I supposed that you will develop a desktop application so I will propose my opinions under the motivation that you will choose Python to develop this project.

First of all, you can use [speech recogition library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) for speech to text. After getting text from speech, we can jump to next step which is analyzing the questions.

At the present time, deep learning is the state of the art and [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) is the great technology to take advantage of deep learning.

[This](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077) is an amazing chatbot framework to build a conversational model for your custom chat bot. You should edit this [JSON file](https://github.com/ugik/notebooks/blob/master/intents.json) to create your conversational intents, after the editing JSON file, you can analyze the questions of user (i.e. your program can understand what user said, the program will parse the question and get the location which is requested by user). When you get the location from question, the program can open browser (for example GoogleMaps) via executing an [Ubuntu terminal command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19919/command-to-open-a-url) in [Python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238180/execute-shell-commands-in-python).

As a summary, when user says "Way from New York City to Washington DC" the program will run respectively;

1. Get text from user speech
2. The program will analyze text via trained system and it can understand that what user said
3. The program can get the destination and current location which is specified by user (many kind of information can get from user request) by using the structure of this [JSON](https://github.com/ugik/notebooks/blob/master/intents.json)[I recommend this way], or may be [NLP](http://www.nltk.org/) or using any kind of string operations
4. The program will start to load Google maps URL via (for example) Ubuntu terminal command for these location information